# How to use variable from function inside a class

Tags: python, function, class, variables

1. From the code below, I want to use variable 'filename' (path to file) to open the file. But it return error NameError: name 'filename' is not defined. What should I do to use the "filename" ?
2. In future, I will use "mdf" variable in other class also. Should I put it after app.exe_() ?

Please give me advise. Thank you

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):         
   def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('MDF_GUI.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        # Find the button with the name "pbutton_load_data"
        self.button1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pbutton_load_data')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.pbutton_load_data_click) # Remember to pass the definition/method, not the return value!
        self.show() # Show the GUI
        
        
    def pbutton_load_data_click(self):
        # This is executed when the button is pressed
        Tk().withdraw()
        filename = askopenfilename()

mdf=MDF(filename)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = mainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the variable, filename, is local to the function; when the function returns it does not exist.  You can use an instance variable and then access it from outside the class.

However, you are not even instantiating the main window until after you have tried to use the filename.

The comment says that the function is called when a button is pressed.  I would expect that this could only happen after the application has opened and is processing input.

So I see several possible options, depending on how your application runs:

1. If run from the command line (since you later use `argv`, you apparently can receive command line parameters), get the filename on the command line
2. Request the information from the user in the 'main' program, before you need the filename, and use it immediately
3. If you must do it in the button clicked function, perhaps you can open the file there (but you will need to instantiate the `mdf` variable as an instance, class, or global variable, depending who uses it, and assign it a default value like `None`. In that case, all code accessing the `mdf` variable would have to check whether it was something other than `None` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put them inside the class?
`self.filename = ...` and `self.mdf = MDF(self.filename)`?